Can an implicit surface be singular over a set of measure that is non-zero?
Let $f:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function such that $S = f^{-1}(0) = \{p\in\mathbb{R}^3\,:\, f(p)=0\}$ is a surface. Let $f$ be continuously differentiable almost everywhere on an open set covering $S$. Can the set $R = \{p\in\mathbb{R}^3 \,:\, \nabla f(p) = 0\}$ have non-zero measure (area), or would this contradict the fact that $S$ is a surface? My intuition is that this cannot happen, but I cannot begin to imagine a way of showing this formally.

It definitely can happen.
The zero-level set of the function $f:\Bbb{R}^3\to\Bbb{R}$ defined as $f(x,y,z)=z^2$ is the plane $\Bbb{R}^2\times\{0\}$, and at every point of the plane, the derivative vanishes. So, the set of points has infinite surface measure (area).

We can make things worse. Let $\phi:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$ be a smooth bump-like function such that

$\phi\geq 0$ and $\phi(z)=0$ if and only if $z= 0$.
$\phi’(0)=0$ (we can even ensure $\phi^{(k)}(0)=0$ for all $k\in\Bbb{N}_0$)
$\phi(z)=1$ for all $|z|>1$.

Now, suppose $n\geq 2$ and define $f:\Bbb{R}^n\to\Bbb{R}$ as $f(x)=\phi(x_n)$. Then, the zero-level set of $f$ is the subspace $\Sigma=\Bbb{R}^{n-1}\times\{0\}$, and the set of points
\begin{align}
C:=\{p\in\Bbb{R}^n\,:\, Df_p=0\}
\end{align}
contains the set $\Bbb{R}^{n-1}\times ((-\infty,-1)\cup\{0\}\cup (1,\infty))$, which has infinite $n$-dimensional measure. Also, the set of points
\begin{align}
C_{\Sigma}:=\{p\in\Sigma\,:\, Df_p=0\}
\end{align}
is all of $\Sigma$ again, so it has infinite surface measure (i.e $(n-1)$-dimensional measure).

This is great, thank you! Is there some mild conditions that can be enforced on $f$ for this to be impossible? For example I was looking at signed distance bound functions. That is if I take a continuously differentiable signed distance function $g$ (it holds $|\nabla g(p)|_2 = 1$ almost everywhere), and I take a signed distance bound function $f$ such that $f^{-1}(0) = g^{-1}(0) = \partial\Omega$, $f$ is continuous, and $0\leq f(p) \leq g(p)$ for $p\in\Omega$ and $0\leq -f(p) \leq -g(p)$ for $p\not\in\Omega$, can a $g$ be constructed such that still I have non-zero measure of this set?

I also found this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_point_of_an_algebraic_variety, more specifically: "Points of V that are not singular are called non-singular or regular. It is always true that almost all points are non-singular, in the sense that the non-singular points form a set that is both open and dense in the variety (for the Zariski topology, as well as for the usual topology, in the case of varieties defined over the complex numbers).[1]" and was under the misunderstanding that the measure should be zero, but maybe this does not transfer or I did not understand it.

You really should ask a separate question for what you actually want to ask

Thank you, I did so: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4980340/can-a-signed-distance-bound-function-surface-be-singular-over-a-set-of-measure-t
I just didn't expect that a counterexample would exist, but as you showed there is even a very simple one.
