Can a signed distance bound function surface be singular over a set of measure that is non-zero?
Motivation
This is a follow-up from my question here: Can an implicit surface be singular over a set of measure that is non-zero?.
I actually thought that the answer would be positive, but surprisingly there was a very simple counterexample that was presented.
The motivation for this question comes from here: Approximating surface normals from signed distance bounds.

SDF and SDBF Definition
A signed distance function (sdf) $f:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}$ for a set $\mathbb{R}^3\setminus\Omega$ (here $\Omega$ is open) is a function defined as:
$$f(p) = \begin{cases} d(p,\partial\Omega), & p\in\Omega, \\ -d(p,\partial\Omega), & p\not\in\Omega,\end{cases}$$
where $d(p,A) = \inf_{q\in A}\|p-q\|_2$ is the smallest distance between $p$ and the set $A$.
A signed distance bound function (sdbf) $g:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}$ for $\mathbb{R}^3\setminus\Omega$ is a continuous function such that $g^{-1}(0) = \partial\Omega$, and $0\leq g(p) \leq f(p)$ for $p\in\Omega$, and $0\leq -g(p) \leq -f(p)$ for $p\not\in\Omega$. That is, it underestimates the true distance to the surface $\partial\Omega$.

The Question
Now let $f$ and $g$ be continuously differentiable almost everywhere on a set covering $\partial\Omega$. Can it happen that the measure of $R = \{p\in\partial\Omega\,:\, \nabla g(p) = 0\}$ is non-zero? Basically, do the conditions on $g$ being a SDBF change anything as to the conclusion of the previous cited question? I believe that $f$ being an SDF should imply that $\|\nabla f(p)\|_2=1$ (if this helps in any way).

Bonus Misunderstading
I have another question/really misunderstanding. I read the following excerpt:

Points of V that are not singular are called non-singular or regular.
It is always true that almost all points are non-singular, in the
sense that the non-singular points form a set that is both open and
dense in the variety (for the Zariski topology, as well as for the
usual topology, in the case of varieties defined over the complex
numbers).

from the wikipedia page on singular points of an algebraic variety. I had understood the singular points to be the ones where the gradient is zero, and the above claims that almost all points are non-singular, so I expected that the measure of $R$ is zero, but the counterexample $f(x,y,z) = z^2$ from 1 shows that this isn't so. Can anyone clarify what I am misunderstanding from the above page?

I believe that $f(x,y,z) = z$ and $$g(x,y,z) = \begin{cases} z, & |z|\geq 1, \\ z^3, & |z|<1,\end{cases}$$ works as a counterexample. The surface $\partial\Omega$ is the plane with normal $(0,0,1)$ at $z=0$, and $f$ is clearly the signed distance function for one of the half-spaces. Moreover $g$ is continuous, $g^{-1}(0)$ gives the desired plane, and $0\leq g(p) \leq f(p)$ for $p_z>0$ and $0\leq -g(p) \leq -f(p)$ for $p_z\leq 0$ by construction.
